# Reason huge performance penalty for >4D arrays MatLab?

Tags: c++, performance, matlab, multidimensional-array, indexing

**Introduction**

I have an algorithm that loops billions (trillions) of times and manipulates a matrix stored in 7 dimensions [10x10x10x10x10x10x10], I found that accessing elements in a 7-dimensional matrix was quite slow, curious as I am I ran some tests to identify the performance of accessing elements of multi-dimensional matrices.

**Hypothesis**

I was reminded that MatLab uses linear indexing under the hood and a friend of mine stated that the performance penalty was probably due to the conversion of 'normal' indexing to linear indexing under the hood [Source](http://www.mathworks.nl/help/matlab/math/multidimensional-arrays.html#f1-86846).

**Testing method**

To test this hypothesis I tested accessing elements using linear indexing and regular indexing for 2D to 7D matrices. I varied the element I was accessing as well as the matrix size I was accessing, i.e. length of each dimension, but that didn't change the results significantly. The file I used for testing is found below. The hardware used is an Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU E5-1620 v2 @ 3.70 GHz, 16GB RAM. The MatLab version is R2013B.

**Results**

```
Normal indexing 2D: 0.073659s
Linear indexing 2D: 0.064026s
Normal indexing 3D: 0.050719s
Linear indexing 3D: 0.064096s
Normal indexing 4D: 0.055674s
Linear indexing 4D: 0.062112s
Normal indexing 5D: 15.689907s
Linear indexing 5D: 5.265076s
Normal indexing 6D: 16.660496s
Linear indexing 6D: 5.295958s
Normal indexing 7D: 17.029072s
Linear indexing 7D: 5.291139s
```

It appears that normal indexing is very similar compared to linear indexing in terms of performance up to 4D matrices. For 3D and 4D matrices it appears slightly preferable to use normal indexing. Above 4D matrices linear indexing is highly preferable over normal indexing, but both normal indexing and regular indexing receive a huge performance penalty (~two orders of magnitude).

**Conclusion**

The moral of the story is to carefully consider the need for more than four dimensions in a matrix when running MatLab when aiming for high performance (apart from the obvious fact that C++ e.g. is for most applications much faster etc. but that's another discussion probably).

**Question(s)**

As in the title: what is the (potential) cause for this huge hit in performance when exceeding four dimensions in a matrix? And do other languages (such as C++) demonstrate this behaviour as well?

*Code used for testing*

```
clear all
clc

% Number if iterations 
n=10000000;

A = rand(10,10);
k1=sub2ind(size(A),3,2);
fprintf('\n')
tic
for ii=1:n
    A1=A(3,2);
end
a=toc;
fprintf('Normal indexing 2D: %fs\n',a)


tic
for ii=1:n
    A2=A(k1);
end
a=toc;
fprintf('Linear indexing 2D: %fs\n',a)

B = rand(10,10,10);
k2=sub2ind(size(B),3,2,1);

tic
for ii=1:n
    B1=B(3,2,1);
end
a=toc;
fprintf('Normal indexing 3D: %fs\n',a)
tic
for ii=1:n
    B2=B(k2);
end
a=toc;
fprintf('Linear indexing 3D: %fs\n',a)

C = rand(10,10,10,10);
k3=sub2ind(size(C),3,2,1,10);

tic
for ii=1:n
    C1=C(3,2,1,10);
end
a=toc;
fprintf('Normal indexing 4D: %fs\n',a)
tic
for ii=1:n
    C2=C(k3);
end
a=toc;
fprintf('Linear indexing 4D: %fs\n',a)

D = rand(10,10,10,10,10);
k4=sub2ind(size(D),3,2,1,10,1);

tic
for ii=1:n
    D1=D(3,2,1,10,1);
end
a=toc;
fprintf('Normal indexing 5D: %fs\n',a)
tic
for ii=1:n
    D2=D(k4);
end
a=toc;
fprintf('Linear indexing 5D: %fs\n',a)

E = rand(10,10,10,10,10,10);
k5=sub2ind(size(E),3,2,1,10,1,2);

tic
for ii=1:n
    E1=E(3,2,1,10,1,2);
end
a=toc;
fprintf('Normal indexing 6D: %fs\n',a)
tic
for ii=1:n
    E2=E(k5);
end
a=toc;
fprintf('Linear indexing 6D: %fs\n',a)

F = rand(10,10,10,10,10,10,10);
k6=sub2ind(size(F),3,2,1,10,1,2,3);

tic
for ii=1:n
    F1=F(3,2,1,10,1,2);
end
a=toc;
fprintf('Normal indexing 7D: %fs\n',a)
tic
for ii=1:n
    F2=F(k6);
end
a=toc;
fprintf('Linear indexing 7D: %fs\n',a)
```

Comment: Just a minor suggestion - you don't even have to save `toc` to `a`!

Comment: I know but I first stored to the tocs in another variable for plotting, a bit a redundant code indeed.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

At some point, there must be an linear address for a value, because that's how most processors work.  The processors are great at fetching data from a single location.

Throughout this answer, the terms *matrix* and *array* will be used interchangably.

**Single Dimension Matrix**
The address calculation for a single dimension array:

```
  address = starting_array_address + (index * sizeof(object_type));
```

The *object_type* is the type of the object, such as `unsigned char` or `int`.

**2 Dimensional Matrix**
The calculation for the index position of a value in a 2D array represented as a 1D array is:

```
  index = Dimension2_value * Dimension1_capacity + Dimension1_value;
```

The address of the value can be calculated using the index and the equation for the Single Dimensional object.

**3 Dimensional Matrix**
The Dimension3_value can be represented as the number of planes inside a cube.
So, this extends the equation by another term:

```
index = Dimension_3_value * (Dimension2_capacity)
      + Dimension2_value * Dimension1_capacity
      + Dimension1_value;
```

**4D & above Matrices**
The calculation for 4D and above matrices can be extended in a similar manner.

The bottleneck in the index calculation are the multiplications.

Some platforms can calculate the terms in parallel, thus giving some speed advantages.

**Speed speculations**
I guess that Matlab has optimized its index calculations for 2D and 3D matrices but not larger ones.  The 2D and 3D matrices are more widely used than 4D and larger.

A typical optimization would be to assign the values of each term to different registers, then sum up the registers.  This is to keep the values as close to the processor as possible.  Some processors may not have enough registers for the 4D calculation and so the compiler may have to place the values in temporary memory (outside the processor), thus slowing down performance.

**Fetching the value**
For 1D, 2D and 3D matrices, the processor may be able to contain the data in its data cache, thus speeding up performances.  As the dimensions grow, the size of matrix must shrink in order for it to fit into the processor's data cache.  Anytime that a value is not in the cache is called a cache-miss and the processor must load the value from memory external to the processor.  Depending on how the data is reloaded, it may reload a "strip" of data or a lot more.  In either case, it's a reduction in performance.

**Summary**
Calculating the index takes more processing time for each additional dimension of a matrix.  The multiplications are the bottleneck of the calculation (even though they may be one instruction, a multiplication takes longer than an addition).  Although each term of the index calculation can be performed in parallel, there may not be enough threads or cores or processing units to perform the index calculation of all the dimensions at one time.  There may not be enough registers or data cache for the optimal calculation, so the processor will have to fetch from external memory, slowing down performance.  If the data item is not in the processor's data cache, the processor will waste time reloading the entire or portions of the data cache (the time is wasted because the processor could be performing calculations instead of reloading the cache).

In general, operating on determinants (smaller sub-matrices) is usually usually results in better performance than operating on a large multi-dimensional matrix.

Comment: Good speculation on register! I was taught that modern compilers take the first 4 arguments into register, while remaining the rest in memory. Matlab's index calculator may have been optimized for up to 4-D indices, natural for a 4-input multiplier. I'm also curious if someone codes in C/C++, how would s/he optimize it?

Comment: I'm not only talking about passing values.  If your processor has 8 registers and 3 are used for passing parameters, there are 5 remaining to use in calculations.  If you need to perform 7 calculations with 5 registers, the remaining calculations need to use memory external to the processor for temporary storage.

Comment: Can anyone use an ARM-based Chromebook to verify this? It suddenly came to me that ARM chips has a lot more registers, so perhaps they could perform better in this issue. But mine is running on a Celeron. Anyone with a Chromebook and crouton-ubuntu can help?

Comment: Read the ARM reference manual: A1.1.1 ARM registers
ARM has 31 general-purpose 32-bit regi
sters. At any one time, 16 of these registers are visible. The other
registers are used to speed up except
ion processing. All the register sp
ecifiers in ARM instructions can
address any of the 16
visible registers.

Comment: So both mine Celeron and OP's Xeon are of x86-64 architecture, having 16 registers, like an ARM does. Does an index conversion involve all of them? Or could it be more complicated

Comment: Print the assembly language for the functions.  The truth is in there.

Comment: I am still wondering why also linear indexing shows a giant decrease in performance when switching from 4 to 4+ dimensions.

Comment: OK I'll have to do some more research tonight but I was pointed by another colleague that MATLAB employs JIT (Just in time compilation) and it might have to do something with that.